# Why does Visual Studio Code mark a false error in my PHP script?

Tags: php, html, css, visual-studio-code

Everything is running well but I ‘m still getting this red underline in the scripts. Any one to explain why and how to remove it? [image]

Comment: does vs code provide any hints if you hover over the underlines?

Comment: @mikerojas Yes  : `';' expected.php`

Comment: Are you using inteliphense? Did you follow the instructions in the setup of that plugin?

Comment: Typically `use ...;` statements go immediately after the `<?php` or `namespace ...;` lines. And one per line; `use App\Domaine\User\User;` then `use App\Domaine\Forem\Message;` on separate lines as you currently have them 

Comment: @gview what do you mean ??  `Disable PHP Language Features. Leave PHP Language Basics enabled for syntax highlighting.` yes i did it but the underline still there

Comment: I glossed over the fact that this line `$user = new User` should  be `$user = new User()` or whatever the constructor requires, if there is one.  Or at least that is best practice, but regardless, your code is valid for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to using the [Inteliphense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) plugin.

The built in PHP language features have issues with some PHP features.  Your code is validated under Inteliphense.

*Remove any other PHP intellisense plugins.*

Make sure that you have followed the Inteliphense instructions when you install it, specifically:

- Go to Extensions.
- Search for @builtin php
- Disable PHP Language Features. Leave PHP Language Basics enabled for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Yop in fact, I uninstall intellisense plugins and the (fals errors) red underline are no longer there. much thank

Comment: Awesome!  Looks like you are learning some features.  Hopefully you will move on to using a composer.json with PSR-4 rule, and include the autoloader it generates.

Comment: I've done this and I'm still getting false errors.